# Need Code/SWD emulator, to program SWD without any adapters or dongles

Tags: python, software-development, source-code, hardware

Goal is to communicate with SWD without any extra hardware, need some kind of code/SWD emulator or anything that can communitcate with SWD ports directly from computer